# Javascript, Does ES5+ still has an activation object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Was reading some information regarding execution context of javascript. I was reading the following [article](https://hackernoon.com/execution-context-in-javascript-319dd72e8e2c) of Rupesh Mishra.

The article stated that a new execution context is created with every new function invocation. An execution context does have 2 phases creation phase and execution phase where the code is executed line by line.

There was stated that an in the creation phase the JS engine does 3 things:

1. Determines the value of `this`
2. Creates the scope chain
3. Creates the Activation or variable object

This was the explanation of the activation object:

> **Creates the Activation object or the variable object:** Activation object is a special object in JS which contain all the variables, function arguments and inner functions declarations information. As activation object is a special object it does not have the dunder proto property.

### Question:

Does `ES5`+ still has this activation object structure? If not, what are the current steps of the creation phase of an execution context?

Comment: I am not sure here, i just found [this article, see note at end of paragraph](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-2-variable-object/#variable-object-in-function-context) where it says "In ES5 the concept of activation object is also replaced with common and single model of lexical environments.", it might have changed with ES5 already

Comment: Changed, the title. But I think you are right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, ES5 (and higher) does no longer use a standard JS object to store variables. It uses [lexical environments](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2) (with `this` value and scope chain) that contain [environment records](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1) of various kinds in which the values for the variables are stored.

> What are the current steps of the creation phase of an execution context?

[Section 10.4 *Establishing an Execution Context*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4) talks about that.

The behaviour is not too different from what ES3 did (after all old code still works), it's just described using new terms.